# Format time from alphanumeric to numeric

Tags: awk

I have a text file:

```
ifile.txt
x       y       z       t              value
1       1       5       01hr01Jan2018   3
1       1       5       02hr01Jan2018   3.1
1       1       5       03hr01Jan2018   3.2
1       3.4     3       01hr01Jan2018   4.1
1       3.4     3       02hr01Jan2018   6.1
1       3.4     3       03hr01Jan2018   1.1
1       4.2     6       01hr01Jan2018   6.33
1       4.2     6       02hr01Jan2018   8.33
1       4.2     6       03hr01Jan2018   5.33
3.4     1       2       01hr01Jan2018   3.5
3.4     1       2       02hr01Jan2018   5.65
3.4     1       2       03hr01Jan2018   3.66
3.4     3.4     4       01hr01Jan2018   6.32
3.4     3.4     4       02hr01Jan2018   9.32
3.4     3.4     4       03hr01Jan2018   12.32
3.4     4.2     8.1     01hr01Jan2018   7.43
3.4     4.2     8.1     02hr01Jan2018   7.93
3.4     4.2     8.1     03hr01Jan2018   5.43
4.2     1       3.4     01hr01Jan2018   6.12
4.2     1       3.4     02hr01Jan2018   7.15
4.2     1       3.4     03hr01Jan2018   9.12
4.2     3.4     5.5     01hr01Jan2018   2.2
4.2     3.4     5.5     02hr01Jan2018   3.42
4.2     3.4     5.5     03hr01Jan2018   3.21
4.2     4.2     6.2     01hr01Jan2018   1.3
4.2     4.2     6.2     02hr01Jan2018   3.4
4.2     4.2     6.2     03hr01Jan2018   1
```

Explanation: Each coordinate (x,y) has a z-value and three time values. The spaces are not tabs. They are sequence of spaces.

I would like to format the t-column from alphanumeric to numeric and then convert to a csv file. My expected output is as:

```
ofile.txt
x,y,z,201801010100,201801010200,201801010300
1,1,5,3,3.1,3.2
1,3.4,3,4.1,6.1,1.1
1,4.2,6,6.33,8.33,5.33
3.4,1,2,3.5,5.65,3.66
3.4,3.4,4,6.32,9.32,12.32
3.4,4.2,8.1,7.43,7.93,5.43
4.2,1,3.4,6.12,7.15,9.12
4.2,3.4,5.5,2.2,3.42,3.21
4.2,4.2,6.2,1.3,3.4,1
The desire time format is replaced with YYYYMMDDHHMin.
```

I had asked part of this question previously. Please see  [Format and then convert txt to csv using shell script and awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502952/format-and-then-convert-txt-to-csv-using-shell-script-and-awk). However I can't able to change the time format within the following script.

```
awk -v OFS=, '{k=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3}
!($4 in hdr){hn[++h]=$4; hdr[$4]}
k in row{row[k]=row[k] OFS $5; next}
{rn[++n]=k; row[k]=$5}
END {
   printf "%s", rn[1]
   for(i=1; i<=h; i++)
      printf "%s", OFS hn[i]
   print ""
   for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
      print rn[i], row[rn[i]]
}' ifile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my answer from your previous question:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {
        SUBSEP = OFS = ","
        month["Jan"] = "01"; month["Feb"] = "02"; month["Mar"] = "03";
        month["Apr"] = "04"; month["May"] = "05"; month["Jun"] = "06";
        month["Jul"] = "07"; month["Aug"] = "08"; month["Sep"] = "09";
        month["Oct"] = "10"; month["Nov"] = "11"; month["Dec"] = "12"; 
    }
    function timestamp_to_numeric(s) {
        # 03hr31Jan2001 => 200101310300
        return substr(s,10,4) month[substr(s,7,3)] substr(s,5,2) substr(s,1,2) "00"
    }
    NR==1 {next}
    {g = timestamp_to_numeric($4); groups[g]; value[$1,$2,$3][g] = $5}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        printf "x,y,z"; for (g in groups) printf ",%s", g; printf "\n"
        for (a in value) {
            printf "%s", a
            for (g in groups) printf "%s%s", OFS, 0+value[a][g]
            printf "\n"
        }
    }
' ifile.txt
```

```
x,y,z,201801010100,201801010200,201801010300
1,1,5,3,3.1,3.2
1,3.4,3,4.1,6.1,1.1
1,4.2,6,6.33,8.33,5.33
3.4,1,2,3.5,5.65,3.66
3.4,3.4,4,6.32,9.32,12.32
3.4,4.2,8.1,7.43,7.93,5.43
4.2,1,3.4,6.12,7.15,9.12
4.2,3.4,5.5,2.2,3.42,3.21
4.2,4.2,6.2,1.3,3.4,1
```

You have to create a mapping between the month name and the month number, then create a function to transform the timestamp to the new format. Beyond that, the code is the same.

Comment: It should be straightforward to update the code you have with this method.

Comment: I would suggest to make use of `sprintf("0.2d",index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",substr(s,7,3))+2)/3)` to get the month. (Kudo's to Ed Morton for this trick)

Comment: meh. Just hardcoding the array is something you only need to do once, and you can use your editor to do the heavy lifting. Don't need to get overly clever.